# Position of label with input text in kivy

Tags: python, input, label, kivy

I had a problem with position of anchor label. Kivy runs this code in middle/center. It's a part of screen display.

```
    with open('weatherdata.txt', encoding='utf-8') as weatherdata:
        read_weatherdata = weatherdata.read()

    label_position = AnchorLayout(anchor_x='right',
                                  anchor_y='bottom')
    label_settings = Label(text=read_weatherdata,
                           font_size='12sp',
                           size=(200, 200),
                           color=(0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1))
    label_position.add_widget(label_settings)
    self.add_widget(label_position)
```

Ex. data from txt file:

```
Weather now in Warsaw, pl 

Clouds: 20 %
Rain: 15 %
Wind speed: 2.6
Wind degree: 340
Humidity: 75 %
Temperature: 5.0 celsius
Max temperature: 5.0 celsius
Min temperature: 5.0 celsius
Weather status: few clouds
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's happening because your `Label` is the same size as the screen. To prevent this you should do `size_hint: None, None`

I'll recommend you to use the [kv lauguage](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html) because it helps to make your code look much cleaner

Here is an example of improved code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout

Builder.load_string('''
<Root>:
    anchor_x: 'right'
    anchor_y: 'bottom'

    Label:
        id: weather_info
        color: 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1
        font_size: '12sp'
        size_hint: None, None
        size: self.texture_size # you can specify you own size here now
''')

class Root(AnchorLayout):
    pass

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        weather_data=\
'''
Weather now in Warsaw, pl

Clouds: 20 %
Rain: 15 %
Wind speed: 2.6
Wind degree: 340
Humidity: 75 %
Temperature: 5.0 celsius
Max temperature: 5.0 celsius
Min temperature: 5.0 celsius
Weather status: few clouds
'''

        self.root = Root()
        self.root.ids.weather_info.text = weather_data
        return self.root


TestApp().run()
```

And as the result we have:

(The font is too small and dark but you can easily change this at any time!)
[image: pic]